# What is disabling the dash package?

Tags: package, smartparens, dash.el

I'm trying to install the `smartparens` package, but I'm having trouble. When I go to <kbd>M-x</kbd> `list-packages`, mark `smartparens` for installation, and hit <kbd>x</kbd> (execute) <kbd>y</kbd> (yes), I get the error message:

> Required package 'dash' is disabled

This is not just for `smartparens`, but for anything that depends on `dash`.

By removing almost all of my packages except `helm-projectile` and its dependencies, I was able to install `dash` from either Melpa or GNU; nevertheless, every time I try to install `smartparens` it complains that dash is disabled.

My essential question is what is going wrong, or what am I missing; and how can I enable `dash` so that I can install things that depend on it?

---

**Supplementary info:**

The value of `package-load-list` is `((helm-core t) (helm t) (async t) (popup t))`

Comment: What is the value of `package-load-list`? Call `C-h v` and input `package-load-list` `RETURN`.

Comment: @Tobias Added the value to my answer.

Comment: The help buffer offers you to customize `package-load-list`. Do so and choose `all` from the `Value Menu`. Delete all other items from this list. Try again the installation of `smartparens`? This is just a guess motivated by [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Installation.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Tobias's suggestion in the comments, I found that `package-load-list` was getting overridden in my `init.el` by a code snippet that I'd gotten from [someone else](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/master/emacs-helm.sh#L84). Commenting out that line didn't seem to affect helm, and it fixed my original problem.

Comment: Please accept you own answer to mark this question as solved in the overview. Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what's up, but this is the second time I've been told this despite the fact that I can't accept my own answer for 48 hours.